# Setting the HSE clock frequency of an STM32

Tags: arm, clock, stm32

I am programming an STM32 (manual [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf)). Page 83 has a diagram indicating that the HSE Clock frequency is between 4 and 26 MHz.

The paragraph on HSE clocks starts on page 84, but does not give any information regarding *setting* the clock to a specific frequency. I have had a look at the RCC registers (starting from page 91) and could find how to turn on/off several clocks, and set various prescalers. I haven't found any register dealing with setting and reading the HSE clock frequency.

How can I read/write the HSE clock frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply the clock to the chip with either a crystal/ceramic resonator or other external clock signal.

The 4 to 26 MHz is not generated by the chip itself...

Comment: Yep, that's right. My dev board has an HSE clock of 25MHz. Thanks.